# Is there any complete downloadable Pokémon TCG text database?

Tags: pokemon

I'm aware those guys have such a database, but I couldn't find any way to download it. Not even access it by an API. Is there any one of those available for download?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a SQL database for cards from Base Set => Double Crisis:

https://github.com/Guernouille/pokeplayer/tree/master/database

http://pokeplayer.com/cardex/search

Comment: Hi, Mega Lag - you appear to be writing as if this place is a discussion forum. It isn't - it's a Q&A site, and you can check our [tour] to see how it works. Answers are expected to answer the question, which in this case would mean an answer should say (a) if there is one available, and (b) where. You don't have comment privileges yet, but when you do, this would be appropriate as a comment. Dokkat no doubt would appreciate the offer, though.

Comment: I actually wanted to comment, but couldn't due to the restriction. So I couldn't comment. I know it is more appropriate to comment in these cases. But I couldn't. Because there's a useless restriction on comments.

Comment: [There's a reason why the comment restriction is there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/152515), actually. Understandable though. This might get converted _into_ a comment.

Comment: Honestly, this is pretty close to an answer. If you happen to have a site already, and could just link to that and say "it's not available today but it will be there in a few days/weeks" I think it'd pretty much be an answer.

Comment: This works as an answer for me.

Comment: As asked, there's the link, I'll release the database and source for search engine as soon as it is finished (I'm currently debugging it) : http://pokeplayer.com/

Comment: Added the GitHub URL, sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late, but better late than never!

I recently developed a Pokémon TCG API that allows anyone to consume Pokémon card and set data in JSON format. It has data from every set, starting with Base. For full details, check out the homepage at https://pokemontcg.io